# How to get a value of column that has Data Annotation 'Browsable' set to False

Tags: c#, datagridview, data-annotations

How to get a value of column that has Data Annotation 'Browsable' set to False?

```
   [Browsable(false)]
   public int IDArtikli { get; set; }
```

I'm using DataGridView and I'm trying to get selectedRows ID value, but since I don't show the ID Column in the datagridview I can't get it via simple code:

```
   int id = -1;
   int index = this.dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index; 
   Int32.TryParse(dataGridView["IDArtikl", index].Value.ToString(), out id);
```

Comment: Try setting the columns visible property to false instead of the browsable annotation. I've hidden columns this way, but were still able to get its value.

Comment: :/ If I really have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if DataGridView is data-bound, you can get all values from the item, associated with row:

```
int id = ((MyClass)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).IDArtikli;
```